# Entity Framework fluent api itself relation same table C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relation

I have a question about relation in simple class. It's class is like a binary tree:

```
class Tree
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Tree LeftChild { get; set; }
    public virtual Tree RightChild { get; set; }
}
```

This has to be the relation of 0..1 to 0..1 - two times (Left and Right Subtree).

How can I do this in fluent API?